# Execute one subroutine by multiple threads

Tags: multithreading, perl, concurrency

Is there a way to execute one subroutine by multiple threads?checked documentation and found out that it's related to use lock() function but it's still executes slower than one thread.Does anyone has any sources on that topic?

Comment: *"but it's still executes slower than one thread"* Please provide a minimal example demonstrating this claim. See [mcve] for more information

Answer (score 3):

Yes, different threads can execute the same code. In fact, this is usually the case.

```perl
use v5.20;
use warnings;
use threads;

use Thread::Queue qw( );
use Time::HiRes   qw( sleep );

use constant NUM_WORKERS => 4;

sub process_job {
   my $job = shift;
   my $tid = thread->tid;
   say "Thread $tid processing job $job...";
   sleep( 1 + rand(1) );  # Sleep 1..2 seconds
   say "Thread $$ completed job $job.";
}

{
   my $q = Thread::Queue->new;

   my @workers;
   for ( 1 .. NUM_WORKERS ) {
      push @workers, async {
         while ( defined( my $job = $q->dequeue() ) ) {
            process_job( $job );
         }
      };
   }

   $q->enqueue( $_ ) for 1..20;   # Add work to queue.

   $q->end();                     # We're done adding work.
   $_->join() for @workers;       # Wait for the threads to complete the work.
}
```

```
Thread 4 processing job 1...
Thread 2 processing job 2...
Thread 1 processing job 3...
Thread 3 processing job 4...
[All four threads are executing `process_job` right here.]
Thread 4 completed job 1.
Thread 4 processing job 5...
Thread 1 completed job 3.
Thread 1 processing job 6...
Thread 2 completed job 2.
Thread 2 processing job 7...
Thread 3 completed job 4.
Thread 3 processing job 8...
Thread 4 completed job 5.
Thread 4 processing job 9...
[...]
Thread 1 completed 16.
Thread 1 processing job 20...
Thread 2 completed 17.
Thread 4 completed 18.
Thread 3 completed 19.
Thread 1 completed 20.
```

If you replace the `sleep( 1 + rand(1) );` with `sleep(1);`, you'll notice the program takes around 20 (number of jobs) divided by 4 (number of workers) = 5 seconds, indicating the work is indeed being done in parallel.